# configuration transfer over scp on commit not working on Juniper EX-2200 switch

Tags: networking, scp, juniper, junos

I am making a series of configuration changes on Junos EX- 2200 switch.I have this router connected to another PC via an ethernet cable.The IP address of the switch is 192.168.1.1.I am able to ping from 192.168.1.1 to 192.168.1.0 and vice-versa.

After the changes I make I do the following commands

```
set system archival configuration transfer-on-commit
set system archival configuration archive-sites "scp://karthik@192.168.1.10:/home/karthik/ws_karthik/sw1_config_1.txt" password godfather

commit
```

Where there is a user with user-name "karthik "
and password "godfather".The path shown above also exists in the system

How ever I don't see the configuration file sw1_config_1.txt created at the path specified.

Also I have verified that sshd is running on the PC (192.168.1.10)

Am I doing something wrong here?

It would be great if anyone could help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to include the filename. JunOS will name the file itself:

Change it to this:

```
set system archival configuration archive-sites "scp://karthik@192.168.1.10:/home/karthik/ws_karthik/" password godfather
```

Make sure to delete your old archive sites (since it doesn't replace them with the new value).